# Replacing words in a sentence from database (Python/Django)

Tags: python, sql, database, django, view

I have a string sentence structure such as this:

Starting in $Duration%, the $Noun$ will be $Adjective$

I need a view to check which words are in "$$" and replace them with a random word from the database which was imported from a SQL file.

Here are the models/sql files:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Type(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=1)


class Word(models.Model):
    dict = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=1)

    def randword(self):
        words = self.objects.all()
        number = randrang(0,len(words))
        return words[number]


class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def randquest(self):
        quests = self.objects.all()
        numbeq = randrang(0, len(quests))
        return quests[numbeq]


class Meta(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    score = models.ForeignKey("Score")
    user = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    time = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Score(models.Model):
    word = models.ForeignKey(Word)
    score = models.IntegerField()
    question = models.ManyToManyField(Question, through=Meta)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.score
```

SQL files

```
INSERT INTO quest_question (question) VALUES ('Starting in $Duration$, the $Noun$ will be $Adjective$');
```

and

```
INSERT INTO quest_word (dict, kind) VALUES ('Coffee Maker', '1');
INSERT INTO quest_word (dict, kind) VALUES ('24 hours', '3');
INSERT INTO quest_word (dict, kind) VALUES ('today', '3');
INSERT INTO quest_word (dict, kind) VALUES ('broken', '2');
INSERT INTO quest_word (dict, kind) VALUES ('Email server', '1');
INSERT INTO quest_word (dict, kind) VALUES ('15 minutes', '3');
INSERT INTO quest_word (dict, kind) VALUES ('tomorrow', '3');
INSERT INTO quest_word (dict, kind) VALUES ('unavailable', '2');


INSERT INTO quest_type (type, value) VALUES ('Noun', '1');
INSERT INTO quest_type (type, value) VALUES ('Adjective', '2');
INSERT INTO quest_type (type, value) VALUES ('Duration', '3');
```

I started writing the view. Need some help with it:

```
from quest.models import Word, Type, Score, Question, Meta
from django.utils import timezone


def question(request):
    sentence = Question.objects.all()
    find_words = re.findall(r"\w+%0-9a-zA-Z%", sentence.question)
```

Comment: Is the `$...$` notation fixed?

Comment: No. I just used the '$' as a marker. It could be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to change the notation, you have two options:

1. [Use Python.](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)

   ```
   >>> 'Starting in {Duration}, the {Noun} will be {Adjective}'.format(Duration='24 hours', Noun='Coffee Maker', Adjective='broken')
   'Starting in 24 hours, the Coffee Maker will be broken'
   >>> 'Starting in %(Duration)s, the %(Noun)s will be %(Adjective)s' % dict(Duration='24 hours', Noun='Coffee Maker', Adjective='broken')
   'Starting in 24 hours, the Coffee Maker will be broken'
   ```
2. [Use Django.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-the-template-system)

   ```
   >>> from django.template import Context, Template
   >>> t = Template('Starting in {{Duration}}, the {{Noun}} will be {{Adjective}}') 
   >>> c = Context(dict(Duration='24 hours', Noun='Coffee Maker', Adjective='broken'))
   >>> t.render(c)
   u'Starting in 24 hours, the Coffee Maker will be broken'
   ```

The rest is pulling from the database and selecting the words at [random](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html), which is the easy part.

Comment: Yes, I can change the notation. With the line 't = Template('Starting in {{Duration}}, the {{Noun}} will be {{Adjective}}'', are you assuming the question stays the same? I would like to also generate it for any question.

Comment: You can pass anything you like to the `Template` constructor.

Comment: How would I change the  
>>> c = Context(dict(Duration='24 hours', Noun='Coffee Maker', Adjective='broken')) so it generates random words?

Comment: Have you taken a moment to look at the link in the last sentence of the answer?